# psycopg2: Argument Binding without connecting to the database (Hive)

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

Is there any way to use  `mogrify` or an alternative method in `psycopg2` to [resolve argument binding](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) without having to connect to the database (Hive in my case) in first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use psycopg2 to construct queries without connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879804/use-psycopg2-to-construct-queries-without-connection)